# How to match vector to data frame based on classes

Tags: r, dplyr

Here I have a tibble containing left and right boundaries (`start` and `end`) defining one class and a vector with random integers:

```r
categories <- tibble(
  start = c(1,10,50,500,600),
  end = c(9,49,499,599,699),
  value = c("Cat01", "Cat02",  "Cat03",  "Cat04",  "Cat05")
)
set.seed(123)
x <- round(runif(20, 0, 699))
```

How to match `x` to column `value`, depending on the class?

Comment: It's working here but not robust if x is out of range (still returns `Cat05`) and e.g. for values exactly 10 returning the wrong value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foo = function(x, start, end) {
    sapply(x, function(v){
        if (v < min(c(start, end)) | v > max(c(start, end))) {
            NA
        } else {
            tail(which(categories$start <= v), 1)
        }
    })
}
categories$value[foo(x, categories$start, categories$end)]
# [1] "Cat03" "Cat04" "Cat03" "Cat05" "Cat05" "Cat02" "Cat03" "Cat05" "Cat03" "Cat03" "Cat05"
#[12] "Cat03" "Cat03" "Cat03" "Cat03" "Cat05" "Cat03" "Cat02" "Cat03" "Cat05"

foo(10, categories$start, categories$end)
#[1] 2
foo(1000, categories$start, categories$end)
#[1] NA
foo(0, categories$start, categories$end)
#[1] NA
```